# Issue trying to bind rss feed to repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to bind a datatable to a repeater. To do this, according to a code sample, I need to call dataview() when choosing the datasource property of the repeater and then write databind().

When I do this, I still get the exception that the source to databind to is not derived from IDatasourceControl.

What is the correct way to bind a datatable to a repeater? I want each record to repeat itself in the repeater (obviously).

I have seen this link (http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/06/21/3469.aspx). What exactly does Container.Dateitem in the expression on the ASPX page mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a repeater you should be able to just do the following:

```
rpYourRepeater.DataSource = dtYourDataTable;
rpYourRepeater.DataBind();
```

That's it.

Just verify that your DataSourceID is tied to a real field in your datatable or just leave the DataSourceID out completely as you don't really need it depending on what you are doing.

You don't need any of that dataview stuff unless you want to start putting filters on your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are attempting to bind to **DataSourceID**. You should bind to **DataSource** in your repeater.